# IEEE 754 calculation discrepancy

Tags: computer-science, ieee-754

I'm getting some discrepancies when I try to convert a float to IEEE 754 format on paper. Specifically, there is  a very tiny difference between my calculated normalized mantissa and the one provided by a calculator. I end up getting the following:

`0 10000101 01001100100010100011110 : 83.1349945068359375`

According to [this website](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), my least significant bit should be 1, not a 0. That's the only difference.

`0 10000101 01001100100010100011111 : 83.13500213623046875`

Upon closer inspection, the one provided by the calculator is slightly more accurate.

```
  83.13500000000000000
- 83.1349945068359375
__________________________
  00.0000054931650625
```

```
  83.13500213623046875
- 83.13500000000000000
__________________________
  00.00000213623046875
```

I'm pretty sure I followed the on-paper algorithm to the letter, and I think my math is tight. I suspect there some added algorithmic layer that provides this final step of accuracy. Does anyone know what it might be?

My calculations are below.

[image: My IEEE 754 conversion of 83.135]

Comment: The calculator provides you the answer that has less tolerance to the real value.
`83.135 - 83.1349945068359375   = ca. +5.5e-6`
`83.135 - 83.13500213623046875 = ca. -2.1e-6`
The absolute value of 2.1e-6 is smaller than 5.5e-6 and therefore the 2nd value is nearer to the real one.

Comment: How is the algorithm done to see which of the two values is better? If your calculation always leads to the ceiling value, then I assume, it just adds 1 to the LSB of mantissa (and if that leads the mantissa to overflow increase the exponent and use mantissa 0 = 0.5) and compares both values with the intended value - which has smaller difference --> that is the result.

Comment: The observation is due to the internal representation used by the calculator. 83.135 isn't exactly representable as an IEEE-754 `binary32`. If the calculator converts the string "83.135" straight into a `binary32` operand, it will actually store the *closest* `binary32` representation with a value of 83.13500213623046 ... instead, and the significand of that is indeed binary `01001100100010100011111`. You should be able to confirm by carrying your own computation to a few more bits, and then *rounding* the result to the *nearest* representable value

Comment: @njuffa I see what you're saying. Taking the mantissa out to  5 more bits and rounding up produces this result. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stopped when you reached the 24<sup>th</sup> bit. But the number was not completely converted. There is a remainder. If the remainder is less than ½, you should round down. If it is more, you should round up. If it is exactly ½, round to make the last bit even.